# Inconsistent Integrate behavior?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, conditional

Evaluating the following integral with *Mathematica*

```
Integrate[q0/(-1 + q0^2), {q0, 0, A}]
```

gives a conditional expression

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[
>     -((I π)/2) + 1/2 Log[-1 + A^2], -1 < Re[A] <= 1 || A ∉ Reals]
> ```

However, evaluating

```
Integrate[q0/(-1 + 12 q0^2), {q0, 0, A}]
```

*Mathematica* returns

> ```
> -(1/24) I (π + I Log[-1 + 12 A^2])
> ```

Is this a bug or is there a reason for this behavior?

(Mathematica Ver.10.3.1)

Comment: And why do you think it is inconsistent?

Comment: shouldn't I get a conditional expr. in the second example?

Comment: Use `12. A^2` and you will see it.

Comment: @Sumit: This makes no sense: I would like to do the integration analytically, thus, why should I use here "12."?

Comment: you can do this: `Integrate[q0/(-1 + b q0^2), {q0, 0, A}] /. b -> 12`  to get your conditional expression. I agree this is an inconsistency.  You can also see the issue if you do `Integrate[q0/(-1 + 12 q0^2), {q0, 0, 1}]` you get a correct message that the integral does not converge while `Integrate[q0/(-1 + 12 q0^2), {q0, 0, A}] /. A -> 1` gives an erroneous result.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with a simpler case

```
Integrate[q0/(-1 + a q^2), q]
```

> $\frac{\log \left(1-a \text{q}^2\right)}{2 a}$

When you put limit `[0,A]`, it has no problem with `q=0`. But it is not defined when $aA^2>1$. So you always have to obey that condition. You can check that by

```
Integrate[q0/(-1 + a q0^2), {q0, 0, A}]
```

In your second case `Integrate[q0/(-1 + 12. q0^2), {q0, 0, A}]` does not show the condition but you can see it in the answer. To avoid this you can use floating number like

```
Integrate[q0/(-1 + 12. q0^2), {q0, 0, A}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[
>    0.103538 + 0.0416667 Log[0.288675 - 1. A] + 
>     0.0416667 Log[0.288675 + 1. A], -0.288675 < Re[A] <= 0.288675 || 
>     A [NotElement] Reals]

If you want to see the condition, then you might want to give mathematica a heads up with an `Assumption` like

```
Integrate[q0/(-1 + 12 q0^2), {q0, 0, A},Assumptions -> A \[Element] Reals]
```

> $\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{1}{24} \log \left(1-12
>    A^2\right),A>0 ~ \&\& ~ 6 A\leq \sqrt{3}\right]$

Otherwise you may not get a condition, specially while dealing with exact numbers.

Comment: My problem is: Following your example: Using a=1 leads to a result which includes the conditional expression. Using a=12 does NOT return the conditional expression, but it should to have a consistent behavior.

Comment: I get your point. Sometimes it happen specially when you work with exact number. It will also happen with 2 or 3.